# Polymer custom elements interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, closures, polymer

I wrote a custom Polymer element that lets the user pick a month. You can look view the code at https://github.com/HoverBaum/month-picker

No I want to use this to select a range of dates. So the user should select a start and and end.
I added two of my  elements to a page, to try this out. However for some reason I can only change the selection of the second element. This looks like the two are somehow interfering with each other. Usually I would say "of cause they use the same ids etc." but I was thinking Polymer would take care of these things.

Here is my little demo page:

```
<div id="timespan">
<span>Start <month-picker></month-picker></span>
<span>End <month-picker></month-picker></span>
</div>
```

The way the  works is that it shows the selected date and when you click it a dialog is opened that lets you change the selected month. But for some reason both element only open the dialog for the second .

Comment: It looks like it could be a bug in the `month-picker` element with the `paper-card` not closing properly on line 171: `</<paper-card>`. Try update it in your `bower_components`. I haven't tested it.

Comment: @Ricky good catch. Fixed that but it didn't solve my issue. Both pickers still open the dialog to pick a month for the second tag.

Comment: Is it displaying the correct `month-picker` when `displayPicker()` is called? A conflict with the `$$` node selector could be happening.

Comment: Ahh I tried to point this out in my last comment. Both tags just open the picker for the second tag. And yeah that looks like the `$$` is getting the wrong thing but I was thinking Polymer would take care of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this problem by sticking more closely to the Polymer syntax. I was trying to not define everything in the options object handed the Polymer function. As it turns out that prevented me from accessing the right dialog.